# Trouble with getting Evernote tags from Sandbox

Tags: java, evernote

The method "noteStore.listTags" returns all tags, including deleted tags from an Evernote Sandbox account. But in API Reference it is said that: "only include active tags". Environment: Java, evernote-api 1.25.1.

1) In my case I need it to return only active tags. Can it be fixed?

2) Does this issue occur only in sandbox or is it happening with premium accounts too? I don't have a premium account, so I can't check.

Environment: Java, evernote-api 1.25.1.

Comment: The documentation is correct, once a tag is deleted it is gone, and isn't returned by listTags. How are you deleting the tag?

Comment: The issue occurs when I sign in on sandbox.evernote.com and delete tags in web UI. I do that to test my app for premium accounts. When I sign in on evernote.com, everything is ok.

Comment: Sandbox and production are separate services, deleting a tag on one service does not delete it on the other. Does that answer your question? The web UI uses noteStore.listTags to show tags too, so if a tag doesn't show up in the web UI it won't show up via listTags.

Comment: Look at the [screenshot dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tj5rf0m0mshorws/2016-02-17%20at%2011-24-02.png?dl=0).
The Evernote API connected to a Sandbox.

Comment: Ah, I see what's going on - we hide any tags that are attached to 0 notes in the UI, so although it hasn't been deleted, it doesn't show up. There's currently no way to actually delete a tag in the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tags you're talking about aren't actually deleted. In the tags drawer in the web UI, we hide any tags that aren't attached to any notes, so although they get returned by [NoteStore.listTags](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_listTags), they aren't shown. We use [NoteStore.findNoteCounts](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_findNoteCounts) to figure out how many notes each tag is attached to. There is currently no way using the web UI to delete tags - you can do that via [NoteStore.expungeTag](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_expungeTag) if you need to.